# Seeking for help for SQL server query to search multiple columns of a table using a combination of keywords

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am having a nightmare in building an efficient search query. I am using LINQ. The requirement is as follows:

In the application there is one text fox field which is used as a **Quick Search**.

The table I will be searching holds three fields **Make**, **Model** and **Extension**.

A typical keyword user can enter is like **Honda Accord XL**

Based on the keywords database should return me the matching rows and here the problem starts. There is no restriction on the order which keywords will be entered to prepare the phrase, i.e. one can enter **Accord XL Honda** or it could be like **XL Accord** or could just be **Honda**. In the example **Honda** is Make, **Accord** is the Model and **XL** is the extension.

Ideally the search result should only pull up perfect matches like if **Honda Accord** is entered it will not bring up other models from **Honda**. But the major problem is I don't know what they will enter and I have to look into three different columns of the table using `Contains` operator.

Here is what I tried:
I spit the phrase into words and place them in an array
`var arr = keyWord.Split(new [] {' '})`. Next step I build the query inside a loop of those array elements:

```
foreach (var k in arr)
{
   var item = new Vehicle();
   var arrayItem = k;
   var query = DataContext.Vehicles.Where(v =>v.RealName.Contains(arrayItem)
               || v.Model.Contains(arrayItem)
               || v.Style.Contains(arrayItem)).ToList();
   foreach (var v in query)
   {
     if(!result.Contains(v))
     result.Add(v);
   }
}

return result;
```

Now when the loop is executing and matching records for **Make** it already fills the list with say 250 items. But how can I remove unwanted items like when a record has **CT** as Model or **TYL** as Extension? If I knew the order of the words in which the keyword was created then I will have the option to remove unmatched Make, Model or Extension from the list by using one line of code for each and return the final result. But in this case if I have to do it I again have to use loop and remove unmatched items, even that will not probably give me the correct data. And definitely this is not the efficient way to do this.

Comment: If the user enters, say, three words (assuming we count `XL` as a word), do you only want to return results that match on all three words? If so, this sounds like a `relational division` problem, if you were to do it purely in SQL.

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit more please?

Comment: Which SQL provider is this? (LINQ-to-SQL, Entity Framework, ...)

Answer (score 0):

--- Try to use Below way your code first retrieve respective make to database ------then filter gettting previous result.

```
List<Vehicle> lsvehicle= new List<Vehicle()>;
foreach (var k in arr)
{
   var arrayItem = k;
   lsvehicle = DataContext.Vehicles.Where(v =>v.RealName.Contains(arrayItem)                ).ToList();
}
foreach (var k in arr)
{
lsvehicle = lsvehicle.Where(v =>v.Model.Contains(arrayItem) || v.Style.Contains(arrayItem)).tolist();
}

return lsvehicle ;
```

Comment: Looks simple but effective :) Let me try this!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by concatenating the Make + Model + Extension string and then comparing that the whole array is contained by this string

```
var query = DataContext.Vehicles;
foreach (var k in arr)
{
   var item = new Vehicle();
   var arrayItem = k;
   query = query.Where(v => (v.RealName + v.Model + v.Style).Contains(arrayItem)).ToList();
}

return query;
```

NOTE: Logical answer, may require syntax error correction if any

Comment: That looks like more of a comment than an answer. For a _better_ answer, you could add an example and better yet, convert original post to fit in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following approach, assuming you have the option to create view in database
and you are searching through three columns

1)Create a view With all combination
2)Use linq to get the record from the view

sql

```
create view [Vw_VehicleSearch]
AS
Select       
   M+V+E [MVE],
   M+E+V [MEV],
   V+M+E [VME],
   v+E+M [VEM],
   E+M+V [EMV],
   E+V+M [EVM]
from
   vehicletable
```

c#

```
public List<string> Search(string quickSearchText)
{
   using(var ctx=new model()))
   {
       var result=ctx
              .Vw_VehicleSearch
              .Where(v=>v.MVE.Contains(quickSearchText)
               || v=>v.MEV.Contains(quickSearchText)
              .|| v=>v.VME.Contains(quickSearchText)
              .|| v=>v.VEM.Contains(quickSearchText)
              .|| v=>v.EMV.Contains(quickSearchText)
              .|| v=>v.EVM.Contains(quickSearchText)
              .ToList();

        return result.Select(r=>r.MVE).ToList();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is: all vehicles of which either `RealName`, or `Model`, or `Style` contains *all* keywords. This can be achieved by:

```
var query = DataContext.Vehicles.Where(v =>
                   arr.All(s => v.RealName.Contains(s))
                || arr.All(s => v.Model.Contains(s))
                || arr.All(s => v.Style.Contains(s)))
           .ToList();
```

Entity Framework is able to translate this query into SQL because it has a trick to convert the array `arr` into a table (of sorts) that can be used in the SQL statement (you should take a look at the generated SQL).

This is not the most efficient way to run a query. It will become considerably slower when the number of keywords becomes "large". I don't think that will be an issue here though.